# Associative set operation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, associativity

Define $A+B=(A\cup B) \backslash (A\cap B)$. Is this set operation associative? I've try to expand $(A+B)+C$ and $A+(B+C)$, but it just became too messy...

Comment: This is going to get messy. Proving operations associative often does. It would help if you showed what you have already done so we can go off that.

Comment: Venn diagrams will help here.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know _indicator functions_, your $+$ operation (which is known as _symmetric difference_ and often notated $A\mathbin{\triangle} B$ or $A\oplus B$) corresponds to pointwise addition modulo 2 of the indicator funcitions of $A$ and $B$. If you know that modular addition is associative, that gets you home.

Comment: Also see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative).